# Copy-Item Combine 2 statements into 1

Tags: powershell

How can I put this command into one statement in powershell?

```
copy-item $temp\tst1.cms $orig
copy-item $temp\tst2.cms $orig
```

what if names are not sequential? like

```
oadmrwc.cms
oadmrwn.cms
```

I'm trying to turn a batch script into a powershell script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work (using wildcard blobbing with Get-Childitem)

```
Get-Childitem $temp\tst[12].cms | Copy-Item $orig
```

or:

```
 Get-Childitem $temp\oadmrw[cn].cms | Copy-Item $orig
```

Answer (score 2):

Would something like this suit?

```
$orig = "c:\temp\"
$items = "one.txt","two.txt", "three.txt","four.txt"

$items | ForEach-Object { Copy-Item $_ $orig}
```

You could put as many items as you want in the $items array then...

Comment: unfortunately not, because the files are generated on the fly by a process, so they wouldn't necessarily all be there all the time, which would move their position in the array. Also not all files need to be moved...+1 tho :)

Answer (score 1):

Parameters `-Path` and `-LiteralPath` are arrays `[string[]]`. So we can specify several items in one command:

```
copy-item $temp\tst1.cms, $temp\tst2.cms $orig
```

Comment: not optimal as mjolinor's answer is probably the most optimal. but plus one homieeeee

Comment: Did you measure? Pipelines are relatively expensive and equivalent commands without pipelines often work faster. Also this command invokes just one cmdlet, cmdlet calls cost, too.

Comment: As for wildcards in `-Path` parameter, you can use them with `copy-item` as well. But the question says "not sequential", so I assumed there is no patterns to apply. Anyway, the more solutions the better :)

Comment: The Help on Copy-Item says the Path parameter will accept a string array, but not wildcards (hence the gci).

Comment: Then the help topic is not quite correct. Most (or all?) of `Path` parameters in MS cmdlets accept wildcards, no matter what help says.